# VB Mortgage Calculator not displaying correct output

Tags: vb.net

My professor is requiring us to create a mortgage calculator using sub procedures. I was able to complete this task all in one button click function without using sub's or ByVal / ByRef. However when I split it up into several different functions and subs I have 0 errors however when I go to click the button and calculate, the 3 display outputs are all 0. I'm assuming it is something in my Function calc block or in my btnCalculate_Click Sub.

```
Public Class frmMortgage

    Dim annualRateOfInterest, monthlyPayment, begBalance As Double 'Declaring variables
    Dim intForMonth, redOfPrincipal, endBalance As Double

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        Call getInput(annualRateOfInterest, monthlyPayment, begBalance)

        Call displayOutput(intForMonth, redOfPrincipal, endBalance)

    End Sub

    Sub getInput(ByVal annualRateOfInterests As Double, ByVal monthlyPayment As Double, ByVal begBalance As Double) 'Values input into txt boxes
        annualRateOfInterest = CDbl(txtInterest.Text) / 100 'Change number entered into a percentage
        monthlyPayment = CDbl(txtPayment.Text)
        begBalance = CDbl(txtBalance.Text)
    End Sub

    Function calc(ByVal annualRateOfInterest As Double, ByVal monthlyPayment As Double, ByVal begBalanceintForMonth As Double, ByVal redOfPrincipal As Double, ByVal endBalance As Double)
        Return intForMonth = (annualRateOfInterest / 12) * begBalance 'Take percentage divided by 12 times beginning balance
        Return redOfPrincipal = monthlyPayment - intForMonth
        Return endBalance = begBalance - redOfPrincipal
    End Function

    Sub displayOutput(ByRef intForMonth As Double, ByRef redOfPrincipal As Double, ByRef endBalance As Double)
        mtbMonth.Text = CDbl(intForMonth) 'Display the calculated data into correct textboxes.
        mtbROP.Text = CDbl(redOfPrincipal)
        mtbEndBalance.Text = CDbl(endBalance)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You didn't use the `calc` function at all. Another is, using `Call` is kinda redundant. You can call your functions/subs without it.

Comment: How do i add that into my click Sub? when i try to call or reference to it I get errors and the program won't run.

Comment: A function is expected to return only **one** value. Notice your code. You are returning 3, and in that case it will only return `intForMonth` which is the first return it sees. And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I tried Call calc(intForMonth, redOfPrincipal, endBalance) the error is BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter.

Comment: Should I split the 3 return values in function calc into 3 seperate functions then? and call to each one seperately in my click sub?

Comment: Are you required to put it into separate subs/functions?

Comment: It does  not matter, as long as the program does what it is supposed to do and I use some sort of Sub Procedures.

Comment: How about just one sub because this can be done in just one sub?

Comment: I initially only used the btnCalculate_click as my only Sub, however he wants to see us use ByVal/ByRef and other sub procedures the button click event has to call to. I already completed once with only the one sub, trying to figure out how to do it an alternate way.

Comment: Check the answer I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just merged it all in one `Sub`.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    ComputeMortgage(Val(txtInterest.Text), Val(txtPayment.Text), Val(txtBalance.Text))
End Sub

Sub ComputeMortgage(ByVal Interest As Double, ByVal monthlyPayment As Double, ByVal begBalance As Double)
    annualRateOfInterest = Interest / 100

    'COMPUTATION
    intForMonth = (annualRateOfInterest / 12) * begBalance 'Take percentage divided by 12 times beginning balance
    redOfPrincipal = monthlyPayment - intForMonth
    endBalance = begBalance - redOfPrincipal

    'DISPLAYING
    mtbMonth.Text = intForMonth 'Display the calculated data into correct textboxes.
    mtbROP.Text = redOfPrincipal
    mtbEndBalance.Text = endBalance

End Sub
```

Comment: There's a lot of casting going on that doesn't need casting...it's redundant

Comment: Thanks! That works great, trying to compare and contrast now to understand all of what is going on. How does the Val call out work ?

Comment: Kindly click the check button if this works. `Val()` returns the value being passed to it as a number. This is to validate and make sure that the value being passed is numeric. If a string with an invalid numeral value is passed, it will return zero.

Comment: I have one last question, the Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click. How do the ByVal Sender and ByVal e lines work ? I don't see them declared anywhere else or understand what they do.